# Flex PopUpManager: How can I detect the existence of a modal popup?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

My Flex 3 application has some modal dialogs displayed via the PopUpManager, but there are times when I'd like other view components to know there is popup displayed. The PopUpManager doesn't have any method for actually checking the existence of popups. Is there any other way to detect this in flash/flex without writing my own global manager?

(also systemManager.popUpChildren.numChildren == 0 even when there's a modal popup)

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it depends on the way you are adding the popup, check the documentation :

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html

create or add popup takes four parameters and fourth parameter is a child list

> childList:String (default = null) —
>   The child list in which to add the
>   popup. One of
>   PopUpManagerChildList.APPLICATION,
>   PopUpManagerChildList.POPUP, or
>   PopUpManagerChildList.PARENT
>   (default).

So try adding all the popup's to a particular child-list and then play around with the size of the list.

Comment: I'll play with those and let you know. They're not very clear how to access the childlist.

Comment: It was the right idea, but I couldn't find documentation about what the childList option *means*, until I found this: http://blog.flexmonkeypatches.com/2007/10/04/flex-close-all-popups/. POPUP setting attaches the popup to the systemManager.popUpChildren list.

Answer (score 3):

In case you have no control on the popups that are created (i.e. you've got a library component that creates popups and the component has not been made by you so you cannot modify it) you can still find all the popups in the application without adding them to a specific list. If interested in a different approach, you can check my blog post at http://www.devahead.com/blog/2009/12/getting-all-the-popups-in-a-flex-application/