# flex PopUpManager.createPopUp ignores PopUpManagerChildList.PARENT

Tags: apache-flex

Ive been trying to get flex popups to open under some of my visual elements, no luck so far, has anyone encountered this problem and maybe have a fix for it?

Comment: Provide example code exhibiting this behavior.

Comment: PopUpManager.createPopUp(viewContainer, popupSettings.viewClass, popupSettings.modal, PopUpManagerChildList.PARENT)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, since the PopupManager is a child of the SystemManager and it handles a lot of other layers on top of the application layer. This first parameter, is only in reference to how it should center the popup if requested via centerPopup(target).

You would need to split your application into segmented layers, and create your own PopupManager that targets one of the middle layers in between.

Comment: there is a fourth parameter for createPopup method PopUpManagerChildList.PARENT, Indicates that the popup is placed in whatever child list the parent component is in.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436754/flex-popupmanager-how-can-i-detect-the-existence-of-a-modal-popup

This is something similar that was answered, Popup's relative to the system manager can be segmented. Meaning even though it would be "bad UI", you can put popup's under an existing one by calling the appropriate 'relative container'.